# How i can add values or elements from the frontend in PostgreSQL arrays by using Express and knex.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, knex.js

How do you add values or elements from the frontend in PostgreSQL arrays by using Express and knex.js?

Comment: I've added an answer to help out, but I suspect your question is fairly likely to be closed because it doesn't really provide enough information to describe your problem. Maybe have a go at storing the data, and posting up a simple, reproducible example when you get stuck?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer: there are no Postgres arrays. However, it's possible that you are referring to a JSON type, storing something which looks like this:

```
"[ 1, 2, 3 ]"
```

Postgres *does* support this, and its documentation can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-json.html).